# How to sign in with Twitter only using javascript  

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter

I was using Django, but i am not successful for signin with Twitter,

So I think maybe should use Javascript to sign in.

How do I sign in using Javascript?

Comment: Maybe stick with Django and try to get that working. Javascript runs in the user's browser and is unlikely to be a good solution for whatever you want to do

Answer (score 2):

You can use Twitter's @Anywhere to let users sign in to their account via JavaScript. Look here for example:

http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#login-signup

Once the user is logged in, you can check their login state **both** from client and from server. On client, just use their provided function, and on server, you can validate the cookie. It is also described in that page.

http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#current-user

Comment: @Anywhere is deprecated and will cease functioning soon

Comment: Why is that deprecated?